# backbone collection filtred in more views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have question Can I make more views for one collection ? Example: I have menu for restaurant there is main menu and drink menu  so when I click to main menu there will be every item and when I click to drink there will be only filtred items, same with food menu and next .... Is this right ? There not will collisions ?

Thanks for answer

Comment: What do you mean by collisions? It's perfectly fine for views to share the same collection. If one view modifies the collection, the collection is modified for all views using that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access the collection from more than one view as a view should only be reading a collection. There will be no collisions assuming that you hide the MainMenuView from the DOM when you display the DrinkMenuView. Alternatively, you could have one menu view and add the logic to function inside the menu view to filter.